# Can some explain me, my mysql match against why not working

Tags: php, mysql, match-against

i am use mysql full text on link column

but some time text match and some time its not working

i have example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470eb28/6

```
CREATE TABLE domains
    (`name` varchar(300))
 ENGINE=InnoDB;
    
INSERT INTO domains
    (`name`)
VALUES
    ('https://www.google.com'),
    ('https://www.yahoo.com'),
    ('https://www.instagram.com/painfreestrength/')
;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_1 ON domains (`name`);
```

query

```
select * from domains where match(name) against('"painfrees"')
```

Comment: Creating a fiddle is nice, but you should also copy its contents into the question. That way, when the link becomes invalid, your question will still hold all the relevant information.

Comment: Must you use `Match` ?

Comment: not working after i change  Match

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470eb28/14

Answer (score 2):

Match against will require you to use whole word

```
select * from domains where MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('wholeword')
```

i.e. for your case

```
select * 
from domains where MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('"https://www.instagram.com/painfreestrength/"')

select * 
from domains where MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('"painfreestrength"')

select * 
from domains where MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('"instagram"')
```

But to if you must use `painfrees`

use `like` or `regex`

```
select * from domains where name like "%painfrees%"

select * from domains where REGEXP_LIKE(name, 'painfrees')
```

Comment: but this search by user, how can i control that, they serach anything

Comment: you want to search across all columns?

Comment: no only one column, also if you serach painfreestrength then worked

Comment: I just need to know what algorithm mysql use on MATCH AGAINST

Comment: @webphp it matches a complete word, the word can also be in between characters. thats why you see the term `FULLTEXT` i suppose

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select * from domains where name like '%painfrees%';
```

Comment: Table have already 1 million rows if i do that then query take long time

Comment: use elastic search. this db is not worth for it then.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you could make it more efficient in terms of performance against a huge database, especially when you are ought to use the LIKE pattern, assuming the table structure is exactly as you put in your question, assuming you already have the column INDEXed.

A viable approach would be to keep the database optimized in alphabetical order with the 'Name' column and LIMIT your search for N rows, this will greatly improve your query.

Another thing you could do is to extract the root domain and keep it in another column, that will improve the performance.